# 2018 Sonata - When my a/c is on it blows out sudden burst of cold air for a few seconds then back to normal

Tags: ac, hyundai, sonata

I have a 2018 Sonata that when the A/C is on  it has started blowing out sudden bursts of cold air.  This only last for a few seconds then it goes back to normal.  It will wait maybe a minute or two and do it again.  It has been extremely hot and humid this year in SC. I've taken the car to dealership and they say: "Normal Characteristic of the Vehicle.  Vehicle uses a variable charge alternator and a blower motor transistor in place of a resistor."   I would like a solution for this problem.

Comment: Why do you think there is a problem? Dealership says this is normal for that vehicle.

Comment: To clarify, does "normal" mean warm air? So you get a burst of cold air, followed by warm air? Do you hear the pump/fans kick on for a moment, then turn off until the next burst of cold air, or do you hear it running continuously?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! To add to the other questions posted here in comments, is this "new" behavior or has it always done this? Did you purchase the vehicle originally? I take it the car is still under the 5yr/60k mile bumper-to-bumper warranty period?

Comment: Paulster2  -  This started about one year ago.  I did purchase this car new from the dealership. The car only has 23,000 miles so it is still under warranty.  Thanks

Comment: the_storyteller --"Normal" means that cold air comes out of the vents like it should to cool the car.  And while the a/c is running like it should there are sudden burst of cold air that comes out and then goes back to the way the a/c should run.  It sounds like the fans kick on just a few seconds at a time. It is sporadic. The sudden burst is not continuously. Thanks